# Sending float from PIC to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, pic, uart

im trying to send float value from pic 16f877a (easypic4 development board) to raspberry pi via uart.

mikroc code

```
AValue = 4.88 * ADC_Read(2)
ptr = (insigned char *)&AValue;
    for (i=0; i < sizeof(AValue);
        UART1_Write(*(ptr+1)), i++);
UART1_Write(0x0a);
delay_ms(100)


import serial, time, struct
from pprint import pprint


ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)

ser.write(raw_input("enter char: "))

while True:

    count = 0
    AValue = []
    for ch in ser.read():
        if ch == "\n":
            AValue = []
            time.sleep(0.1)

    while count < 4:
        for ch in ser.read():
            AValue.append(ch)
            count += 1

    flt =struct.unpack("<f",str("".join(AValue)))
    pprint (flt)enter code here
```

output in python shell on raspberry pi. the value is changing as i move the pot around as you can see but only the zero value is correct. actualy not even zero since first value should be 1*4.88

```
(0.0,)
(-1.1472824864025526e-35),
(-3.2123910193243324e-35),
(-4.405564851100735e-35),
(-3.0045950051756514e-32),
```

Comment: It would probably be enlightening to inspect the raw bytes you're receiving in the Python code (i.e. before the conversion to float). One possible cause is that the PIC and Pi CPUs use different endian-ness, and you need to swap.

Comment: i already tried that. not working. i dont own a logic analyzer to do some probing!

Comment: ['\xe1', '\xca', '\x08', '\x8b'] this is what comes out. it should be 4997,12

Comment: Try converting float to string using sprintf() and then write it on UART.

Comment: sprintf uses too much memory and can not be done on pic16f877a

Comment: Transmitting multi-byte binary values is problematic without a message frame or packet.

Comment: can u elaborate on that sawdust....

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, Microchip use custom float format.

Here you can see both translations of `4997,12` number

```
0F6h, 028h, 09Ch, 045h    ; IEEE Real       = 4997,12
0F6h, 028h, 01Ch, 08Bh    ; Microchip Real  = 4997,12
```

[image]

For more information about read: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00575.pdf

**EDIT: added x86 asm conversion rutines...**

```
procedure AnsiSingleToMFormat(var Data: single);
asm
  mov       cx,[eax + 2]
  rcl       cl,1
  rcl       ch,1
  rcr       cl,1
  mov       [eax + 2],cx
end;

procedure MFormatToAnsiSingle(var Data: single);
asm
  mov       cx,[eax + 2]
  rcl       cl,1
  rcr       ch,1
  rcr       cl,1
  mov       [eax + 2],cx
end;
```

Comment: yes thank u GJ. just have to figure out now how to spin those bits around.

Comment: @Anže Zorin: On PC under x86 asm is just few lines, check my update. :)

Comment: i oppted for a different solution. im sending a string representation of float and convering it back to float on raspbbery side. but i have a problem at low values 007,7465 it just prints 0. im using fastnumbers module now for conversion becouse normal float would just crash on nonprintable char. any ideas

Comment: i should add that when i try to fast_float("007,8754") in shell outside my program it returns a string?? wtf

Comment: @Anže Zorin: Use debugger and set brek point before sending value via connection and check it!

Comment: why does floatToStr append those zeros at beginning an how can i avoid that? i tried deleting them in python on rasberry but no success!! :(